# Error ora-12550 with oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, oracle, connection, oracle-manageddataaccess

When i execute my code i have the following error :

```
ORA-12550 : The supplied connect descriptor contains illegal syntax.
```

I checked if i have the correct syntax on http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora and nothing seem bad so i don't know 
whence can this error.

```
public static OracleConnection GetDBConnection(string host, int port, String sid, String user, string password)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST="+host+")(PORT="+port+"))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME="+sid+")));User Id="+user+";Password="+password;
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connString;
        return conn;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, "ADDRESS" has double "D".
Also ADDRESS is a part of ADDRESS_LIST so try 
    `(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =
       your_host)(PORT = your_port)  )  )`